# Can Azure Traffic Manager guarantee requests isolation in deferent Geo regions?

Tags: azure

I am trying to understand how to design the distribution of an application.
The plan is to replicate the whole app in different geographic regions(EU,US,Asia) and use  Azure Traffic Manager to handle the requests distribution.

The thing is that the app has a special need where the requests should be isolated within a region. The US users should be directed only to US data center, EU users to EU data center and so on. 
The requirement is to prevent the traffic randomly going to different data centers, for example: a US user makes few requests to US data center and then few requests to EU data center.

Also it is important to note that this is not about request stickinesses. What I need to achieve is that all users from same city/country always get directed to the same data centers.

Only at a point of data center failure ALL the requests can be directed to another region.

Is it possible to create such configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my understanding it seems you can do this via the "Performance" Load Balancing Method. [This Hands-on-Lab provided by Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/wazplatformtrainingcourse_windowsazuretrafficmanager.aspx) gives a step by step process to setting up the Traffic Manager to handle requests based on geography.